# trigger java program

Tags: java, triggers, apache-axis, mule, ofbiz

I have a remote Java web service client based on Axis2 that invokes a web service in OFBiz on another machine. However, My supervisor insists that i use Mule esb to invoke the OFBiz web service as it is the integration platform we are using or our project at hand. OFBiz uses request maps which makes it very hard to invoke its web services using CFX or JAX-WS in Mule. I can invoke the web services using Axis2, but Mule does not support Axis2, hence cannot use an Axis2-based java client as a Mule component. So my plan is to have a java component in mule that can automatically trigger the Axis2-based client to run when the component starts to run in the flow. I tried making the Project with the Axis class part of the Mule project and import all the Axis2 jar files. Then call the Axis2 java client by instantiating it in the Mule Java component. But when i run the mule flow, it complain that it cannot find the logger for Axis2. I know Mule does not support Axis2.

So my question is, How can i trigger the Axis2-based Java client by another java class in a different project without creating an instance of that class to make the call? All i want is - if my Mule component runs, it should trigger the Axis2-based java client to execute too. Thanks

Comment: I don't follow you fully: you've generated the Axis2 client classes for the OFBiz service and when you use the client classes from your flow you get a problem?

Comment: I have an Axis2-based client that consumes an OFBiz SOAP-based web service. I initially wanted to consume the web service using CFX/JAX-WS in Mule, but had many issues. So i finally succeeded using Axis2 outside Mule. Mule does not support Axis2. But since my project requires that i use Mule, how can i have the Axis2 program run automatically following a certain event in Mule? I would like or this he Axis2 to start based on the execution of a POJO component in Mule. Hope this shades more light on the question

Comment: It does but I don't get what prevents you to do just that, ie use your Axis2 client classes from your flow, like from an expression component or similar.

Comment: Mule does not support Axis2 and hence throws the "cannot find logger" when i try to call the program from Mule (and yes, the Axis2 jar files have been placed in Mule for this).

Comment: I don't think you need to manually install JARs in Mule for this, just add the Axis client dependencies to your project's POM. I guess it'll also bring the logger class through transitive dependency.